# SharePoint 2007 development environment access

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Can I buy online access for a SharePoint 2007 development environment?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a SharePoint DEV cloud offering take a look at [CloudShare](http://www.cloudshare.com/) as they have [predefined SharePoint DEV environments](http://www.cloudshare.com/solutions/sharepoint.aspx).

Please note: I am not affiliated with this company.